# please get me started on querying DB with c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database

i need to get started with accessing a database with c#

please give me the simplest example possible!!

perhaps a mysql database would be the simplest example?

please show me how to connect to a mysql database and get data

Comment: Lots of factors conspire to make it simpler to connect to MS SQL Server. You may even already have MS SQL Express installed somewhere if you have Visual Studio installed...

Comment: you are right i have ms sql express installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use MySQL, you'll need to get a [.Net Data Provider for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html) or a MySQL ODBC driver.

Or you could install SQL Server Express Edition ([free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff&DisplayLang=en)).

Then just walk through a beginner tutorial, of which there are plenty on the web: [MSDN tutorial here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937(v=VS.80).aspx), [one here](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=454), another [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseAcessWithAdoNet1.aspx), and [here is a simple MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(VS.80).aspx) covering ADO, ODBC, OleDB.

Really there is a huge wealth of help out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [decent example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp) of accessing databases in .net from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie wrote a very nice (and lengthly) [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/435498.aspx) on data access using ASP.NET.

To keep things simple, you only need to look at the following:

1. tutorial 1 - focus on option 2
2. tutorial 2 - skip the part about advanced options

Guthrie provides code in VB.NET.  I'll rewrite the code in C# (which should be placed within the scope of the Page_Load method under Default.aspx):

```
NorthwindTableAdapters.SuppliersTableAdapter suppliersAdapter = 
    new NorthwindTableAdapters.SuppliersTableAdapter();

Northwind.SuppliersDataTable suppliers = suppliersAdapter.GetAllSuppliers();

foreach (Northwind.SuppliersRow supplierRow in suppliers)
    Response.Write("Supplier: " + supplierRow.CompanyName + "<br />");
```

By the way, the entire tutorial is worth reading.